np.array limits number of characters in each element
I create an numpy 1D array with 10 elements, each element = "low"
I change an element to "high", only "hig" is inserted.
Apparently, each element is limited to 3 characters.
I want to create the array without limiting the number of characters in each element.
In the code below the first X returns:
array(['low', 'low', 'low', 'low', ....
After the substitution of the element at index 2, X returns:
array(['low', 'low', 'hig', 'low', ....
I want the second X to return:
array(['low', 'low', 'high', 'low', ....
import numpy as np

X = np.array(["low"]*10)
X #This returns array(['low', 'low', 'low', 'low', ...
X[2] = 'high'
X #This returns array(['low', 'low', 'hig', 'low',...


If you are really storing strings saying "high" and "low", you might find you do rather better with dtype=bool.

NumPy is setting the default string length as 3 based on the initial string "low".
You should set an appropriate dtype.

If you know the maximum string length (in your example it's 4 for "high"), then:

X = np.array(["low"]*10, dtype='<U4')


To accommodate any length of string (less efficient):

X = np.array(["low"]*10, dtype=object)


If you only have 2 options "high"(True) and "low"(False), then the most efficient would be:

X = np.array([False]*10, dtype=bool)


Ok, found an explanation here https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-numpy-dtype-astype/  Scroll down to "The number of characters in strings"
numpy creates the array with the maximum number of characters allowed in an element = the longest element.  In my case this is 3.  That is what dtype='<U3' indicates when you print the array.  To allow additional characters in an element specify the datatype as dtype = 'U#' where # is the number of characters desired.  I want to substitute "high" for "low" so dtype = 'U4' will work as indicated in the code below:
import numpy as np

X = np.array(["low"]*10, dtype = 'U4')
X

This returns:
array(['low', 'low', 'high', 'low', ...])

My first thought: If it is only low and high, you could rather use boolean arrays. Those would also help in comparing, manipulation...
X = np.array([False]*10)
X[2]=True
print(['high' if x else 'low' for x in X])

This snippet results in
['low', 'low', 'high', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low']

which is very close to your desired output. Doesn't that also solve your problem? Even if you have more than two strings that might occur, I would think of encoding them in an integer/enum rather than always adapting to the longest string. This also makes it easier to maintain the code, exchange or translate a string later, etc.
